# Select all rows where the sum of price equals or 1000 in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to select all rows where sum of price columns is 1000 or below. How can I achieve it with Laravel ? please suggest. I am new to laravel.

My table has only 4 colum

1. `id`
2. `userid`
3. `order_id`
4. `price`

i need to select all rows using `traditional DB::table('orders')->select()... query (not using model)`, where total value of price column is 1000.

Comment: You should provide more information, especially your table structure and maybe a model also. So for now your question is not clear enough. For example do you have one or more price columns, what is the name of the column/columns? You should now get the idea on how to expand your question.

Comment: hi, i updated question

Comment: I would suggest using Eloquent with something like: `Orders::where("price","<=",1000)->get();`.  In case you want to group it by `order_id` then this should work `Orders::groupBy('order_id')
   ->selectRaw('sum(price) as sum, id, userid, order_id')
   ->get();`

Comment: What do you mean by "all rows where the sum of price columns is 1000 or below"? Each row has only one price column, how can it have a sum? Do you mean the total of all rows in an order, or the total of all rows for a user ID?

Comment: The answer you accepted can't possibly be right, it should get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know OP asked for RAW SQL statement, but since using **Laravel**, the best way to get these orders, is to leverage **Laravels Eloquent** engine like this:

```
$orders = Orders::select(userid, order_id, DB::raw('SUM(price) as price_total'))
->groupBy('order_id')
->havingRaw('SUM(price) <= ?',[1000])
->get();
```

BTW It would be better if **userid** would stick to laravels convention like **user_id**, but that's another case.

You should be able to group this request to userid easily, instead of `order_id` if that's your intent.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Bart answer

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')
       ->where('price','<=',1000)
       ->select(
         DB::raw(
            'col1,
             col2,
             col3,
             sum AS "price_total"')
      )
      ->get();
```